# Sensor QT0805X-102J

Tags: thermistor

I needed to use a sensor to measure variations in temperature from inspired and expired air. But since i am doing a simulation in TINA-TI i am limited in the sensors I can use. I thought of using this sensor, since it had the shortest thermal time constant (of 8 seconds).

I wanted to know if this sensor would be a good option for this system, and if has any disadvantages

Here is its datasheet: https://www.datasheets360.com/pdf/-1548591290487189880

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, it's just an opinion: -

Given that the thermal conductivity of expired air is going to be higher than that of the air breathed in (due to exhaling air with added moisture content), I think you may get unforeseen errors. But it all boils down to how accurate you want the system to be and what your overall aims are.

If you wanted uncompromising accuracy, I'd use two thermistors arranged in a bridge with an op-amp to measure both temperature and thermal conductivity together.